# How can I iteratively partition the same string multiple times?

Tags: python

I have a string of unknown length that can repeat the pattern of interest any number of times. 
The string looks like so:

> blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
>
> blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
>
> JOHNNYSMITH has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 14:18
>   blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
>
> blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
>
> JOHNNYSMITH has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 14:19
>
> SARAHJOHNSON has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 17:45
>   blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
>
> SARAHJOHNSON has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 17:46

I'm trying separate out the comment, username, and date to create a nicer looking comment box (with some css). The following is what I have to separate the user name

```
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = stringg.partition("has entered the above notes on ")
namedate = before_keyword.split()[-1] + "--" + after_keyword.split()[0] + after_keyword.split()[1]
comment = before_keyword.replace(before_keyword.split()[-1], '').rstrip()
print comment
print namedate
```

This works for the first case of Username entered the above notes. How can I iterate through the string to collect all comments/usernames/dates in the string and print them out separately.

Thanks.

Edit: put in fake names instead of USERNAME2389 to show how the names appear for me.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I guess for now just printing them all out works for me, I'll add it to my post.

Comment: What do you want to do if the user enters this note:  "USERNAME2839 has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 14:19"

Comment: @wim, what happened there was someone just entered a blank note, so it'll just have their name and date with a blank note.

Comment: You should remove all of the 'BLAHs' and put in better examples

Comment: It's just random information about down process equipment, I don't think it will provide any more clarity than the blahs. Users just type why they logged a piece of equipment down and then the comment is thrown above a line that says:

 USERNAME857 has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 17:46. 

All comments are added this way until the tool is logged into a different "state" and then the string is erased and a new one is started.

Comment: @Trumsey  No you misunderstand what I meant.  A user TROLLUSER literally entered the note "USERNAME2839 has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 14:19".

Comment: @wim Well the tool logging is only used by about 10 people in my department and I know them all personally. So I guess I could just go talk to them about not doing that.

Comment: @Trumsey  Good answer.  My point was more this: what you want is impossible in the general case, and if you want to parse this with Python code, you should consider to use a more machine-friendly output at the other end (such as json or yaml).

Comment: Ah I see, sadly I work for a largecompany and the string output is from a huge piece of software used everywhere. I'm just making a report for some of the engineers on shift but it only takes our tools into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regular expressions to do this.

Simply loop through every line (FOREACH), then test the line for this expression:

```
(USERNAME\S*) has entered the above notes on (\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) (\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})
```

If this line matches, you have your 3 information (in parentheses): Username, Date and Time. Store the lines before that in an array (buffer) and you'll have your text.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the lines, create a text placeholder and when a username hits append it to a dataframe so at the end you have a nice, manipulatable dataset. You can also convert the datetime's directly so you can analyze more around the times, dates, etc.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

string = """
    blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

    blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

    USERNAME2398 has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 14:18 

    blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

    blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

    USERNAME2839 has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 14:19

    USERNAME7348 has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 17:45 

    blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

    USERNAME857 has entered the above notes on 12/05/2017 17:46
    """


# define regex for username matching
username = re.compile('USERNAME.*?\s', re.IGNORECASE)
# define regex for datetime matching
datetime_re = re.compile('[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/(20|19)[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}')
# create placeholder datfarame
masterdf = pd.DataFrame()
# define text placeholder
cur_text = ''
for line in string.split('\n'):
    if datetime_re.search(line) and all([x.isupper() for x in line.split()[0]]):
        # pull out username
        cur_user = line.split()[0].strip()# username.search(line).group(0)
        # pull out datetime
        cur_datetime = datetime_re.search(line).group(0)
        # convert to datetime object
        cur_datetime = datetime.strptime(cur_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
        # create row to append to dataframe
        row = pd.DataFrame({'user': cur_user,
                       'datetime': cur_datetime,
                       'text': cur_text}, index = [0])
        # append row to dataframe
        masterdf = masterdf.append(row)
        # reinit cur_text
        cur_text = ''

    else:
        # if not a username line, continue appending the commentary for the user
        cur_text += line
```

Comment: This is a good solution and I think I can rework it for my case. The only problem is I screwed up and should've been more explicit in my explanation. The USERNAME2589 appears as JOHNNYSMITH, ROBERTHANSEN, etc. I tried to take names out for protection but I should have put in real "fake" names. I'm sorry for wasting your time with an incomplete question.

Comment: Are they all capitalized like that? Find the common pattern that differentiates a username from the rest of the text. If they are indeed all capitlized and thats different, then I would split off the first 'word' of the line and test it for an all caps item using all([x.isupper() for x in word]). And this might be a solved problem, are the dates only on username lines? If thats the case, that is your answer. Test for the dates. Also, you could look for 'has entered the above notes'. I think there is a lot to work with that would still give you precise information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Bernz worked, I'm using something like the code shown below. datawrestler's answer would also work.

```
for line in stringg.split('\n'):
      if re.findall('(\w+) has entered the above notes on (\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) (\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})', line):
        print line.split()[0] + "--" + line.split()[-2] + line.split()[-1]
      else:
        print line
```